# Truncate file at front

Tags: filesystems

A problem I was working on recently got me to wishing that I could lop off the front of a file. Kind of like a “truncate at front,” if you will. Truncating a file at the back end is a common operation–something we do without even thinking much about it. But lopping off the front of a file? Sounds ridiculous at first, but only because we’ve been trained to think that it’s impossible. But a lop operation could be useful in some situations.

A simple example (certainly not the only or necessarily the best example) is a FIFO queue. You’re adding new items to the end of the file and pulling items out of the file from the front. The file grows over time and there’s a huge empty space at the front. With current file systems, there are several ways around this problem:

- As each item is removed, copy the
  remaining items up to replace it, and
  truncate the file. Although it works,
  this solution is very expensive
  time-wise.
- Monitor the size of the empty space at
  the front, and when it reaches a
  particular size or percentage of the
  entire file size, move everything up
  and truncate the file. This is much
  more efficient than the previous
  solution, but still costs time when
  items are moved in the file.
- Implement a circular queue in the
  file, adding new items to the hole at
  the front of the file as items are
  removed. This can be quite efficient,
  especially if you don’t mind the
  possibility of things getting out of
  order in the queue. If you do care
  about order, there’s the potential of
  having to move items around. But in
  general, a circular queue is pretty
  easy to implement and manages disk
  space well.

But if there was a lop operation, removing an item from the queue would be as easy as updating the beginning-of-file marker. As easy, in fact, as truncating a file. Why, then, is there no such operation?

I understand a bit about file systems implementation, and don't see any particular reason this would be difficult.  It looks to me like all it would require is another word (dword, perhaps?) per allocation entry to say where the file starts within the block.  With 1 terabyte drives under $100 US, it seems like a pretty small price to pay for such functionality.

What other tasks would be made easier if you could lop off the front of a file as efficiently as you can truncate at the end?

Can you think of any technical reason this function couldn't be added to a modern file system?  Other, non-technical reasons?

Comment: One big advantage of such an operation is that it would avoid erase cycles on flash media.

Comment: In the meantime this topic already as a bug into the "truncate" linux man page. I'm sure some day it will be implemented, 20 years after i first asked for it

Comment: same problem as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/339483/how-can-i-remove-the-first-line-of-a-text-file-using-bash-sed-script although more explicit here

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Truncate files at front seems not too hard to implement at system level.

But there are issues.

- The first one is at programming level. When opening file in random access the current paradigm is to use offset from the beginning of the file to point out different places in the file. If we truncate at beginning of file (or perform insertion or removal from the middle of the file) that is not any more a stable property. (While appendind or truncating from the end is not a problem).

In other words truncating the beginning would change the only reference point and that is bad.

- At a system level uses exist as you pointed out, but are quite rare. I believe most uses of files are of the write once read many kind, so even truncate is not a critical feature and we could probably do without it (well some things would become more difficult, but nothing would become impossible).

If we want more complex accesses (and there are indeed needs) we open files in random mode and add some internal data structure. Theses informations can also be shared between several files. This leads us to the last issue I see, probably the most important.

- In a sense when we using random access files with some internal structure... we are still using files but we are not any more using files paradigm. Typical such cases are the databases where we want to perform insertion or removal of records without caring at all about their physical place. Databases can use files as low level implementation but for optimisation purposes some database editors choose to completely bypass filesystem (think about Oracle partitions).

I see no technical reason why we couldn't do everything that is currently done in an operating system with files using a database as data storage layer. I even heard that NTFS has many common points with databases in it's internals. An operating system can (and probably will in some not so far future) use another paradigm than files one.

Summarily i believe that's not a technical problem at all, just a change of paradigm and that removing the beginning is definitely not part of the current "files paradigm", but not a big and useful enough change to compell changing anything at all.

Answer (score 16):

On file systems that support sparse files "punching" a hole and removing data at an arbitrary file position is very easy. The operating system just has to mark the corresponding blocks as "not allocated".  Removing data from the beginning of a file is just a special case of this operation. The main thing that is required is a system call that will implement such an operation: ftruncate2(int fd, off_t offset, size_t count).

On Linux systems this is actually implemented with the [fallocate](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/en/man2/fallocate.2.html) system call by specifying the `FALLOC_FL_PUNCH_HOLE` flag to zero-out a range and the `FALLOC_FL_COLLAPSE_RANGE` flag to completely remove the data in that range.  Note that there are restrictions on what ranges can be specified and that not all filesystems support these operations.

Comment: Thanks, I added that.

Answer (score 1):

NTFS can do something like this with it's sparse file support but it's generaly not that useful.

Answer (score 1):

may can achieve this goal in two steps

```
long fileLength; //file total length
long reserveLength; //reserve length until the file ending
int fd; //file open for read & write

sendfile(fd, fd, fileLength-reserveLength, reserveLength);
ftruncate(fd, reserveLength);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a bit of a chicken-and-egg problem in there: because filesystems have not supported this kind of behavior efficiently, people haven't written programs to use it, and because people haven't written programs to use it, there's little incentive for filesystems to support it.

You could always write your own filesystem to do this, or maybe modify an existing one (although filesystems used "in the wild" are probably pretty complicated, you might have an easier time starting from scratch).  If people find it useful enough it might catch on ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Actually there are record base file systems - IBM have one and I believe DEC VMS also had this facility. I seem to remember both allowed (allow? I guess they are still around) deleting and inserting at random positions in a file.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a unix command called `head` -- so you could do this via:

```
head -n1000 file > file_truncated
```