# What's the opposite of head? I want all but the first N lines of a file

Tags: command-line, scripting, tail, unix-head

Given a text file of unknown length, how can I read, for example all *but* the first 2 lines of the file? I know `tail` will give me the last N lines, but I don't know what N is ahead of time.

So for a file

```
AAAA
BBBB
CCCC
DDDD
EEEE
```

I want

```
CCCC
DDDD
EEEE
```

And for a file

```
AAAA
BBBB
CCCC
```

I'd get just

```
CCCC
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I remove the first line of a text file using bash/sed script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339483/how-can-i-remove-the-first-line-of-a-text-file-using-bash-sed-script)

Comment: This question already has answers [here](/q/339483) and [here](/q/604864).

Answer (score 284, accepted):

`tail --help` gives the following:

```
  -n, --lines=K            output the last K lines, instead of the last 10;
                           or use -n +K to output lines starting with the Kth
```

So to filter out the first `2` lines, `-n +3` should give you the output you are looking for (start from 3rd):

```
tail -n +3
```

Comment: Oddly, my man page doesn't list the option, but it works just fine - thanks!

Comment: @Nicholas: Weird, I figured it would be standard documentation regardless of the OS.  I pulled that from Cygwin inside Windows, so I don't know what it looks like in various Linux distros.  Glad it worked.

Comment: @NicholasMTElliott [man7](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tail.1.html) lists it like Joe Enos' manpage, so it's likely to be a manpage version issue

Comment: @SteveJorgensen: I don't understand what your comment is referring to; no one seems to be suggesting to use `head` for this?

Comment: Probably obvious to everyone but me, but +K is the _1-indexed_ Kth line, so e.g. `tail -n +1` is equivalent to `cat`. To get all but the first line, you need to do `tail -n +2`.

Answer (score 30):

Assuming your version of tail supports it, you can specify starting the tail after X lines.  In your case, you'd do 2+1.

```
tail -n +3

[mdemaria@oblivion ~]$ tail -n +3 stack_overflow.txt
CCCC
DDDD
EEEE
```

Answer (score 14):

A simple solution using awk:

```
awk 'NR > 2 { print }' file.name
```

Comment: One of us is confused. The questions says: "all but the first 2 lines of the file".  How does that command not meet the requirement?

Comment: `{ print }` is the default action, and can be omitted.

Answer (score 10):

Try `sed 1,2d`. Replace 2 as needed.

Comment: worked as expected.. as number of lines after first 2 lines are unknown.

Answer (score 9):

`tail -n +linecount filename` will start output at line `linecount` of `filename`, so `tail -n +3 filename`
should do what you want.

Comment: This wouldn't work in my shell but `tail -n +17 filename` would. I use bash/ubuntu LTS

Comment: @iso: Thanks for the heads-up -- older versions of `tail` accepted the syntax I used in my original answer, but now one needs to use the explicit `-n` option.  I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Use this, supposing the first sample is called sample1.dat then `tail --lines=3 sample1.dat` which would print all lines from the 3rd line to the last line.

For the second sample, again suppose it is called sample2.dat it would be `tail --lines=-1 sample2.dat` which would print the last line...

Comment: @Jim: what's the difference with yours and mine?....same thing.... :o I was referring to the two sample data file inputs as per his question and showing how to achieve what he was looking for....

Comment: Ok... then why did he ask for the second sample and showed the result he wanted which is what I used 'tail --lines=-1'...... of course you can omit the filename completely and its still can act as a pipe... hmm

Comment: @tommie: Oops, forget what I said about pipes...I must have been thinking of some other utility.  But my point was that a single command,`tail +3 anyfile`, gives the desired results for the general case, while `tail --lines=N` requires knowing N in advance to give the desired result.

Comment: @tommie: But this is `tail`...shouldn't that be "bottoms up"?  (Ba-dum TISH!  Thank you, I'll be here all week...)

Answer (score 0):

The `head` function supports this with negative numbers.

```
head --help

-n, --lines=[-]K         print the first K lines instead of the first 10;
                         with the leading '-', print all but the last
                         K lines of each file
```

For example, a positive number prints the first 2 lines.

```
 head -n +2

 AAAA
 BBBB
```

A negative number prints all *except* for the *first* 2 lines.

```
head -n -2

CCCC
DDDD
EEEE
```

Note that unlike with `tail` this does not require prior knowledge of the total number of lines in a file. It excludes the first 2 lines regardless of how many lines there are. Negative numbers for `tail -n -2` can similarly be used to remove the *last* 2 lines of a file.

Note this uses GNU head version 8.22. This feature may not have been available at the original time of release. It is now available even if fairly old linux distros.

Comment: Sadly on the Mac (here using macOS 12.6), head does not accept negative numbers like head -n -2 to skip that many lines at the start (it complains "illegal line count"). However while undocumented, tail -n +3 with a plus three does work for starting at line three (suggested in another answer).

Answer (score -1):

I really don't know how to do it from just tail or head but with the help of `wc -l` (line count) and bash expression, you can achieve that.

```
tail -$(( $( wc -l $FILE | grep -Eo '[0-9]+' ) - 2 )) $FILE
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This requires a complete pass over the file before running tail. If the file is greater than the size of memory this will be very inefficient. It does not handle files less than two lines. It does not handle the file changing size between the wc and the tail.

Comment: @janm: You are all right. Other answers are just better. I feel embarrass. :-p

Answer (score -1):

using awk to get all but the last 2 line

```
awk 'FNR==NR{n=FNR}FNR<=n-3{print}' file file
```

awk to get all but the first 2 lines

```
awk 'NR>2' file
```

OR you can use more

```
more +2 file
```

or just bash

```
#!/bin/bash

i=0
while read -r line
do
  [[ $i > 1 ]] && echo "$line"
  ((i++))
done <"file"
```

Comment: Now this doesn't meet the requirement. The question says "all but the first 2 lines of the file" and gives two examples, each with a single file, where the first two lines are skipped and the remainder of the file is sent to stdout. That is not what this command does.

Comment: yes i misread the question. thought he is ask for all but last 2 lines.