# Delete or replace first line of 3500 php files

Tags: linux, security, server, malware

I have an old server, all php files are compromised by a malicious code on the first line of all files.
I would replace the first line by a simple line that contains `<?php`

could you advise me a linux command for doing this ?

thank you

Comment: If your server is compromised this won't make it safe. http://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the opposite of head? I want all but the first N lines of a file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3507999/whats-the-opposite-of-head-i-want-all-but-the-first-n-lines-of-a-file)

Comment: Sorry disregard dupe. I thought maybe it would help b/c you could just get rid of the first line but I forgot they have to start with `<?php`. Maybe you could still use it.

Comment: these are old site, once cleaned, with appropriate permissions will be not bad

Comment: Why in the world would you want to change the first line to `<?php`? That seems like you're trying to make your code executable...

Comment: read above :
all php files are compromised by a malicious code on the first line of all files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I write this :

```
    grep 'create_";global' -rl | xargs sed '1 s/^.*$/<?php/g' -i
```

and I think it doing the job

Answer (score 1):

To check

```
grep '\$efidomat.*\$otunim);'   *.php
```

To delete in a directory

```
sed -i 's/\$efidomat.*\$otunim);//'   *.php
```

To delete in directory tree

```
find . -type f -exec  sed -i 's/\$efidomat.*\$otunim);
```

---

**Parameters**

`$efidomat` - the beginning of "my" malicious code.

`$otunim`   - the end       of "my" malicious code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small python script that will work its way through all *.php files in its folder and create a modified version in a subfolder called new_files. Don't forget to create that subfolder before running the script!

```
    import glob

    for f in glob.glob("*.php"):
        f_in=open(f,"r")
        f_out=open("new_files/"+f,"w")
        f_out.write("<?php\n")
        for l in f_in.readlines()[1:]:
            f_out.write(l)
        f_out.close()
        f_in.close()
```

I know it's not a linux command but if you create a file called "script.py" and install python the linux command would be "python script.py". Haha just kidding, I hope it is still helpful ;)