# Unix script to remove the first line of a CSV file

Tags: unix, csv, vi

I've stated before I'm not very good at scripting so what I have below copies files from a share directory to mine where I change their permissions. But then I wanted to remove the first line in each of the CSV files — the headings — and then I wanted to get this to run every hour.

```
cd /users
scp dehpc14_Disk_Quota_Report.csv /h/u544835
scp dehpc14_User_Disk_Usage.csv /h/u544835
cd /h/u544835
chmod 755 dehpc14_Disk_Quota_Report.csv
chmod 755 dehpc14_User_Disk_Usage.csv
```

*** insert delete csv first line here ***

Can anyone help me with deleting the first line of the CSV file and getting this to run automatically every hour, for example, or direct me to something I might understand to get cracking with it?

Answer (score 110, accepted):

You can delete the first line of a file using `sed`:

```
sed -i '' 1d file.csv
```

If you just want to get the contents of the file without the first line, and **without** modifying the file, remove the `-i ''` flag:

```
sed 1d file.csv
```

Here 1d is the command to execute:

- **1** => line where to act
- **d** => delete

So **1d** means 'delete line 1'

If you want to get the first line, you can use sed too:

```
sed -n 1p file.csv
```

Here **p** stands for 'print' or

```
sed 1q file.csv
```

(see William Pursell's comment)

Comment: Thanks very much for both the answer and the explanation

Comment: The 'sed 1p file.csv' example will print the first line twice, and every other line once.  To print only the first line, you need 'sed -n 1p' (although it is more common to do 'sed 1q' and quit after printing one line.)

Comment: Note that this answer only applies to GNU `sed`; it does not work with BSD `sed`, also found on Mac OS X. BSD `sed` requires a suffix after the `-i`; if you do not want a suffix, use `-i ''` (with space). But the manual page explicitly recommends against that. See [Unix script to delete the first line on a Mac](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29482817/) for the details.  Other Unix systems (AIX, HP-UX, Solaris, etc) may not have the `-i` option at all; it is not mandated by the POSIX specification for [`sed`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html)

Comment: @RKR this shouldn't take long (maybe if you have a huge file). What's your filesize and time to complete? Using exactly which command?

Comment: This is the command I used. `sed 1d file.csv`  .It took more than 20-30 minutes for a 3 GB file.

Comment: For folks getting the ERROR `1d: no such file or directory`, do this instead `sed -i '1d' filename.csv`

Answer (score 18):

I tried to delete the first row from a CSV, cd into the location and then the answer to the question didn't work for me, was getting

> sed: can't read 1d: No such file or directory

So, I've used the following stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27099557/5675325) by @amit

```
sed -i '1d' filename.csv
```

Answer (score 3):

To create a new CSV file without the header, you can do the following:

```
sed 1d file_with_header.csv > file_without_header.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

While looking for this answer I also found this other thread.   There they say use tail, which doesn't actually make an modifications which is what the OP wanted.  You could over course copy to a temporary file.  Additionally, if you were going to stream the files into another tool, you could use 'tail' in a pipe and never have to write temporary files or write to disk.

[How can I remove the first line of a text file using bash/sed script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339483/how-can-i-remove-the-first-line-of-a-text-file-using-bash-sed-script)