# Unix script to delete the first line of a file on a Mac

Tags: macos, unix, sed

On my Mac, when I try to run:

```
sed -i 2d file.csv
```

from the answer to [Unix script to remove the first line of a CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9633114/unix-script-remove-first-line-of-csv-file), I get the following error:

```
sed: 1: "file.csv": invalid command code f
```

What can I do if I would like to delete the first two lines of `file.csv`?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

On a Mac, the BSD `sed` requires the suffix for the backup (but the suffix can be an empty string, `''`) — it is not optional as it is with GNU `sed`.  Hence, your command is being interpreted as "backup the file with the suffix `2d` and … oops, the script you gave is `file.csv`, but `f` isn't a `sed` command".

```
sed -i .bak -e 2d file.csv
```

This deletes the first line of data from the CSV file (leaving the heading line in place).

If you want to write the code so it works with both BSD and GNU `sed`, then you have to attach the suffix to the `-i` option (GNU `sed` requires the suffix attached to the `-i` option; that's how it identifies whether there's an optional suffix or not):

```
sed -i.bak -e 2d file.csv
```

Note that you can't use an empty suffix and have the command work with both BSD `sed` and GNU `sed`.

The `-e` isn't necessary in either command line, but I quite often use it.  I also often quote the command in single quotes, though it isn't necessary here.

If you want to delete the first two data lines, use `2,3d` as the command.  If you want to delete the first two lines, use `1,2d`.

If you don't want the backup, then you can either remove it after the `sed` command completes (easiest) or use the two stage or three stage dance:

```
sed 2d file.csv > file.csv.bak &&
mv file.csv.bak file.csv            # Oops; there went the links

sed 2d file.csv > file.csv.bak &&
cp file.csv.bak file.csv
rm -f file.csv.bak
```

With these, you might need to add `trap` commands to clean up the intermediate `.bak` file if an interrupt or other signal terminates the script.

---

To quote from the Apple documentation for `sed` — which was originally quoted by [Diego](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4178025/diego) in an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29482906/15168) which he chose to delete, the `-i` option takes an argument which indicates the extension to use for backup copies.

> `-i` *extension*
>
> Edit files in-place, saving backups with the specified extension. If a zero-length extension is given, no backup will be saved. It is not recommended to give a zero-length extension when in-place editing files, as you risk corruption or partial content in situations where disk space is exhausted, etc.

Comment: This deletes the item in the second row, but not the first row: " sed 2d file.csv > file.csv.bak &&
cp file.csv.bak file.csv
rm -f file.csv.bak"

Comment: I covered how to delete the first two lines in the file, and how to delete the first two data lines in the file.  What more do you want?

Answer (score 3):

`sed -i.bak '2,3d' filename.csv` will delete lines 1 and 2 (assuming you have headers)

What this command does is edits the file being referenced while simultaneously creating a backup of the original file (hence the usage of `.bak`). The line deletion `'2,3d'` will delete the 2nd and 3rd line of the original file.

Comment: What if I don't have headers?

Comment: Then use '1,2d' instead of '2,3d'

Comment: What if I don't want to create the backup file that appears?

Comment: Then see Diego's post below and don't use .bak

Comment: This works, deleting the first two data lines from the file, and works with both GNU `sed` and BSD `sed`.  However, you haven't really explained why it works.

Comment: What this command does is edits the file being referenced while simultaneously creating a backup of the original file (hence the usage of .bak). The line deletion '2,3d' will delete the 2nd and 3rd line of the original file. Hope this clears it up.

Comment: Your comment is good, but belongs in the answer.  You can edit your answer to improve it, and you should do that normally.  I've done it for you this time.

Comment: My apologies. I'm new to giving answers on StackOverflow so didn't realize I wasn't following best protocol. Just wanted to help out.