# deleting 1st row of many files at once in vim

Tags: vim, buffer

I'm trying to edit all the files at once using vim buffers. Is it possible to delete 1st row of each file opened in buffers?

Comment: you can use tail http://stackoverflow.com/questions/339483/how-can-i-remove-the-first-line-of-a-text-file-using-bash-sed-script instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Check out the `:bufdo` command](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/windows.html#%3abufdo)

Specifically, what you want is `:bufdo! 1d`

Answer (score 2):

you can do the task with `:bufdo 1d | update`

Answer (score 1):

`:tabdo 1d` works for me in gVim, but that's across multiple tabs. I'm not sure how buffers differ—you might need to use `:bufdo` instead.

Check here for more info:

http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Run_a_command_in_multiple_buffers