# linux truncate first line - is there a better method

Tags: linux, bash

There is the following which will truncate a file to take the first line and overwrite it,
I wonder if there is a cleaner way then to do this:

```
touch temp.txt; cat versions.txt | head -1 > temp.txt; mv temp.txt versions.txt
```

Note that this does not work:

```
cat versions.txt | head -1 > versions.txt
```

and the `touch` is not necessary on most systems

Comment: Why do you cat files, when you can directly write `head -1 versions.txt > temp.txt` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I remove the first line of a text file using bash/sed script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/339483/how-can-i-remove-the-first-line-of-a-text-file-using-bash-sed-script)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it with sed in one command:

```
sed -i -n 1p versions.txt
```

Comment: if the file is large, it's more efficient to do `sed 1q file`

Comment: definitely best solution

Answer (score 4):

Here's one way of doing it in-place

```
ex -c ':2,$d' -c ':wq' versions.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

Use sed like this:

```
sed -i.bak '1d' file
```

Answer (score 3):

Ho about this

```
ONE=`awk 'NR==1 {print;exit}' versions.txt`&& echo $ONE>versions.txt
```