# Terminal: Remove the first row of a file

Tags: terminal, rstudio

I am new to mac terminal. I would like to ask: how can I remove the first row of a csv file ?

Because currently the csv file contains an unnecessary row, which cause to fail to load the csv file in Rstudio.

The first row of the csv file contains the words "dataset offered by ABC company". Can someone teach me how to remove the first row of this csv in mac terminal ?

(Note that the csv are too large to be opened normally and these files sit on a server not on my local machine)

Thanks

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/339483/how-can-i-remove-the-first-line-of-a-text-file-using-bash-sed-script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can use bash this should do the trick:

`tail -n +2 input.csv > output.csv`

It copies input file starting form the 2nd line.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SED` command.
Something like this:

```
sed 1d input_file.csv > output_file.csv
```

Comment: When I used this command, it deleted the entire file, not just the first line.