# Deleting first row of each csv file using sed

Tags: bash, csv, sed

I am trying to delete the first row of each of my .csv files in my DIR folder using the sed:

```
DIR=/home/results
for filename in "$DIR"; do
        sed 1d filename.csv
done
```

However, this doesn't work. I am new to bash scripting and would be thankful if anyone tells me how to fix this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I remove the first line of a text file using bash/sed script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/339483/how-can-i-remove-the-first-line-of-a-text-file-using-bash-sed-script)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do:

```
for f in /home/results/*.csv; do sed -i '1 d' "$f"; done
```

The glob pattern `/home/results/*.csv` matches all `.csv` files in `/home/results/` directory and then the `for` construct iterate over the files, `sed` does the in place removal of the first row from each file.

Comment: Thank you so much! This works and now I want to have a new row as a first line of this which I am trying to do by echo "col1, col2, col3" > all.csv but it doesnt work. Do you have suggestions for this?

Comment: @rehm20 You could do that using `sed`: `for f in /home/results/*.csv; do sed -i '1 s/.*/col1, col2, col3/' "$f"; done`